# Spark: How to group and count RDD that meet certain condition?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

My `RDD`'s type is `RDD[Map]`, and the `map` format is like:

```
{"date": "2015-01-01", "topic": "sports", "content": "foo,bar"}
 ...
```

Now I would like to obtain a sequence like

`{"date": "2015-01-01", "topic":"sports", "count":22}`

that is, the count of every topic for each day.

How to group and count it in `Spark`?

Comment: How would you do it in another language? You could also convert it to a DataFrame and use SparkSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using spark sql on spark 1.3.0, this code is well tested and if you are familiar with sql you can write simple queries to process your JSON data. Please note that syntax is little different in latest version of Spark (for eg: 1.5):

```
Save file to HDFS (eg: /user/cloudera/data.json)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10");
-- You can change number of partitions to the number you want, by default it will use 200
import sqlContext.implicits._
val jsonData = sqlContext.jsonFile("/user/cloudera/data.json")
jsonData.registerTempTable("jsonData")
val tableData=sqlContext.sql("select \"date\", topic, count(1) from jsonData group by \"date\", topic")
tableData.collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Map` is an object having the fields you have shown, you can simply do this:

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

 resultRDD=yourRDD.map( x => ((x.date,x.topic), 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
 resultRDD.map (
  x =>
   // here you have to create the JSON you want as output
   // knowing that x._1._1 contains the date, x._1._2 contains the topic
   // and x._2 contains the count
 )
```

The code I have written i in Scala, but I'm sure it'll be easy for you to adapt it to your language if you're using Java or Python.

Moreover pay attention to the import I put since it's necessary to have an implicit conversion between a `RDD` and a `PairRDD`.